# how to compile PHP to use non-system cURL on OSX El Capitan WITHOUT homebrew, macports or disabling SIP

Tags: php, macos, curl, compilation, osx-elcapitan

As part of setting up a developer environment on OSX10.11 El Capitan I am have trying to compile php7.0.8 to make use of a freshly installed version of cURL (currently v7.49.1) instead of Apple's system install of V7.43.0 which uses SecureTransport instead of openSSL.
I found a good reference which I've mostly followed here: http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/php/. 
And this has kindly been updated to include a quick fix for php support of openSSL which was found not to compile without errors either! [possibly a php configure bug? TBC]
cURL installs consistently without issue and overwrites the system install so can be used from the command line.

my [existing] cURL installation:

```
    ./configure 
    --prefix=/usr/local/curl-7.49.1 
    --with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl
    ln -s /usr/local/curl-7.49.1 /usr/local/curl
    echo 'PATH=/usr/local/curl/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile 
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

I previously tried a usr/local prefix but this was similarly not used by php:

```
    ./configure 
    --prefix=/usr/local 
    --with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl
    echo 'PATH=/usr/local/bin/curl/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile 
    source ~/.bash_profile)
```

I've also tested this same compile sequence using php v5.6.23 sadly with the same results.
php compiles without errors but the result is that php remains linked to the system cURL and not the one referenced by the configure script.

my php configure command:

```
    ./configure 
    --prefix=/usr/local/php-7.0.8 
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-7.0.8/etc 
    --enable-intl 
    --with-icu-dir=/usr/local/icu 
    --enable-bcmath 
    --enable-mbstring 
    --enable-sockets 
    --enable-zip 
    --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs 
    --with-bz2 
    --with-curl=/usr/local/curl 
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/freetype 
    --with-gd 
    --with-imap-ssl 
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/libjpeg 
    --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/libmcrypt 
    --with-mysqli 
    --with-pear 
    --with-pdo-mysql 
    --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/postgresql 
    --with-pgsql=/usr/local/postgresql 
    --with-png-dir=/usr/local/libpng 
    --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl 
    --with-xmlrpc 
    --with-xsl 
    --with-zlib'
```

I've also tried the 
--with-curl option (without a directory specified) 
both compile without error but php still references the system cURL.

my ~/.bash_profile:

```
    export PATH=/usr/local/curl/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/autoconf/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/openssl/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/openssl/ssl/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/git/share/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/cmake/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/cmake/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/mysql/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/memcached/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/memcached/share/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/redis/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/pcre/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/apache/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/apache/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/postgresql/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/postgresql/man:$PATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/php/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/php/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/node/share/man:$MANPATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/graphicsmagick/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/icu/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=/usr/local/src/composer:$PATH
```

`# which curl` finds my fresh cURL install
    `/usr/local/curl/bin/curl`

```
    curl --version
    curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0) libcurl/7.49.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2h zlib/1.2.5
    Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
    Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

[phpinfo output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULZV4.png)

The standard output of the php configure script displays my installed curl version each time (not the system version) which implies that the configure script has found my intended cURL but then compiled php ignores this?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is:

After running the `configure` command including the option: `--with-openssl=/path/to/my_new_openssl_dir`  , is to edit the php src Makefile, and remove all instances of `-libcrypto` and `-libssl` within the `EXTRA_LIBS=` section before adding the full paths to the newly installed libcrypto & libssl libraries:  `/path/to/my_new_openssl_dir/lib/libssl.dylib /path/to/my_new_openssl_dir/lib/libcrypto.dylib` (making sure there is a space between them and the previous library entries).

This allowed me to compile the most recent stable php7.0.8 with OpenSSL/1.0.2h and curl 7.49.1 on OSX 10.11 El Capitan without disabling SIP to add overriding symlinks and without using HomeBrew.